# generate transaction number in C#

Tags: c#, mysql, transactions

I have a C# application with a Transaction No. in windows form. I need to generate my transno. whenever i press the button to generate the transaction no. it will promp me a messagebox that says

I try to change the query from like '%" + sdate + "'" to like '" + sdate + "%'"

> near 1 transno from tblcar where transno like '20200605%' at line 1

```
private void GetTransNo()
    {
        try
        {
            string sdate = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd");
            string transno;
            int count;
            con.conDB.Open();
            cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT TOP 1 transno from tblcart where transno like '" + sdate + "%'",con.conDB);
            dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            dr.Read();
            if (dr.HasRows)
            {
                transno = dr[0].ToString();
                count = int.Parse( transno.Substring(8, 4));
                lblTransaction.Text = sdate + (count + 1);
            }
            else
            {
                transno = sdate + "1001";
                lblTransaction.Text = transno;
            }
            dr.Close();
            con.conDB.Close();

        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            con.conDB.Close();
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, stitle, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
        }
    }
```

[image: picture 1]
[image]

Comment: [link] https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F9LIzZAox1U&list=PL0VHAkRIxGQ7RLUtxdA6CBlVLT_K3m4SC&index=27 By the way. im following this tutorial

Comment: TOP 1 is for Sql Server. MySql uses LIMIT 1 at the end of the query

Comment: There are also other errors in your code. a) You are using a global connection object, not good for scalability and performances of your server and your application. b) You are calling Read and then HasRows. Just looking at the return value of Read is enough. c) But the most dangerous error is the string concatenation instead of using a parameterized query

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/bc5EPew getting error again @Steve

Comment: `cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT LIMIT 1 transno from tblcart where transno like '" + sdate + "%'",con.conDB);`

Comment: LIMIT 1 goes at the end of the query after the WHERE or ORDER BY statement. Did you look at the duplicate question?

Comment: bit confusing where to put LIMIT 1 `("SELECT transno FROM tblcart where transno like '" + sdate + "%',LIMIT 1", con.conDB);`

Comment: @KennyTan then checkout the accepted answer in the duplicate question, it shows you the syntax.

Comment: thank you. I already fix the issue